# Find the slope of the line using least squares method

Tags: least-squares, pseudoinverse, slope

This question is taken from GATE 2005 ICE subject paper.

> Using the given data points given below, a straight line  passing through the origin is fitted using least squares method.
>
> $$(x, y)$$
>   $$(1, 1.5) \thinspace (2.0, 2.2) \thinspace (3.0, 2.7)$$
>
> The slope of the line is ?
>
> a) 0.9
>   b) 1
>   c) 1.1
>   d) 1.5

### My solution

$mX = Y$

m$ \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3
    \end{bmatrix} $ = $ \begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    y_2 \\
    y_3
    \end{bmatrix} $

Since the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse [can be](http://adityaarpitha.blogspot.com/2016/01/polynomial-curve-fitting.html) used to compute a 'best fit' (least squares) solution.

$$m = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$$

$$ m = (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^3)^{-1}(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3) = 
 \frac{1.5+4.4+8.1}{1 + 4 + 9} = 1 $$

Thus the answer is **(b)**

---

While this is the answer given in this book (Arihant publications - Chapterwise previous year solved papers (2013-2000) GATE Instrumentation Engineering - Page 200) that I am following,

[image: solution]

0.6 is touted as the answer in various other places too - [gate overflow](https://gateoverflow.in/33743/gate-2005-probability-and-line), While I found [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=o8LODAAAQBAJ&lpg=SA4-PA17&ots=5YKdz5v4zB&dq=Using%20given%20data%20ponts%20tabulated%20below%20a%20straight%20line%20passing%20through%20origin%20is%20fitted%20using%20least%20squares%20method%20the%20slope%20of%20the%20line%20is&pg=SA4-PA17#v=onepage&q=Using%20given%20data%20ponts%20tabulated%20below%20a%20straight%20line%20passing%20through%20origin%20is%20fitted%20using%20least%20squares%20method%20the%20slope%20of%20the%20line%20is&f=false) (Q 101) agreed with me.

So which is actually correct and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the question. Different questions imply different answers.

> Q1: Using the given data points given below, a straight line passing
>   through the origin is fitted using least squares method. What is the
>   value of a if the regression function is $y=ax$

Answer: The value of the slope a is equal to $1$

> Q2: Using the given data points given below, a straight is fitted using least squares method. What are the
>   values of a and b if the regression function is $y=ax+b$

Answer: The values of a is $0.6$ and the value of b is $\frac{14}{15}$

These questions can be solved without using matrix algebra, since we have 3 data point only. Just minimize

$\sum_{i=1}^{3} (y_i-ax)^2 =(1.5-a)^2+(2.2-2a)^2+(2.7-3a)^2$ respectively

$\sum_{i=1}^{3} (y_i-ax-b)^2 = (1.5-a-b)^2+(2.2-2a-b)^2+(2.7-3a-b)^2$

Here are the results of [Q1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Min%20(1.5-a)%5E2%2B(2.2-2a)%5E2%2B(2.7-3a)%5E2) and [Q2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Min%20(1.5-a-b)%5E2%2B(2.2-2a-b)%5E2%2B(2.7-3a-b)%5E2).